# How can I give the root (superuser) the ability to log in to a desktop like all the other users?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop, root

I used to be able to login to a desktop environment in Linux Mint even as the root superuser until I had a partition disaster and had to re-install it.

Now I can't remember the terminal command I used to enable the root to login to it's own desktop. I tried using the users and groups program from the desktop, but that doesn’t work; it says root already exists.  I seem to remember that there is a command (an old UNIX command I think) that will work from a terminal.

Does any one know what it is?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I'd like to ask that you please do not do this. It opens up your entire system to effects from any browser bug you hit, among other things. Instead, could you please expand on why you would want this?

Comment: Ive been used to doing this for years - ever since I became a Linux/Unix user - and found it easier to use all parts of the system for root and admin purposes - and for other purposes too like when researching things relavant to the needs of using the PC as root - for other activities I use other desktop accounts. I compartmentalise my life in this way. I have had no problems with having a root desktop so far.

Comment: Here's the problem. What if there's a problem with, say, Cinnamon, that caused it to accidentally `rm -rf /usr`? That exact situation has happened with two different programs. Please read https://askubuntu.com/a/16179/300807, and make sure you understand the risks. I will now post an answer.

Comment: So assuming good faith you say, “I think it was something like user something.” You know, I honestly am not to sure what that means.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly advise you against doing this, even with the compartmentalization you mentioned.

Why? Here's the problem. What if there's a problem with, say, Cinnamon, that caused it to accidentally `rm -rf /usr`? That exact situation has happened with multiple different programs. Please read this post on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/16179), and make sure you understand the risks.

If you still feel like this is worth the risk, here is what you need to do:

1. Make sure root has a password (`sudo passwd root`)
2. For lightdm, edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. Add this line:

   ```
    greeter-show-manual-login=true
   ```

   For mdm, edit `/etc/mdm/mdm.conf`. Add this line:

   ```
    AllowRoot=true
   ```

Then reboot (or restart lightdm), and you should be able to log in as root.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Why was it removed and why is it not in the edit history? It's not a sensitive link.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Oh, your wording gave me the impression that you were part of removing it. I'll add it back in now. Thank you!

Comment: I dont have lightdm or gdm - it turns out I have something called mdm. Is the syntax the same?

Comment: @Mark No, but I'll update my answer later. What version of Mint are you on?

Comment: Sarah version 18 I think

Comment: @Mark Added mdm instructions

Comment: Yes it worked! I added this to my mdm file - then went to the GUI and went into settings for the Login screen - and there was a radio button giving me the option to login as Root - checked it - and now I can login as Root! Thanks all.

Comment: @Mark No problem. If my answer helped you, please click the green checkmark to the left to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD this didn't work so ...

In `/usr/local/etc/lightdm/user.conf`

```
minimum-uid=0
```

In `/usr/local/etc/pam.d/lightdm` comment out with a hash like as follows:

```
\# account               requisite       pam_securetty.so
```

The user.conf change might not be necessary but pam certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

The old unix command that allows you to assume the role of root is called `su`
as in `su -`

you can also do it for just one command via
`sudo`
as in `sudo rm -rf /tmp/`

It's generally not good form to log in as root at all as it masks who the actual user was whereas if you login as Mark and then "su -" it will show that you were root user at the time, even better if you login as Mark and the "sudo some-command" it will be noted that you ran some-command as root

Answer (score 0):

With again all the warnings that it is **strongly advised against**, you can also log in as root in a console and start a graphical session with

```
startx -- :1
```

(or another display number)